# Elementary questions about regular rings and Zariski tangent spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

So I've got 3 rather related questions, which all seem to be true, except maybe the third. I'm asking because I remember thinking about this in the past and encountering a difficulty with all 3.

First question:

> Let $S$ be an integral domain, and $\mathfrak{m}$ a maximal ideal, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal contained in $\mathfrak{m}$. Is the Zariski tangent space of $S/\mathfrak{p}$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ just $\mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{p}+\mathfrak{m}^2)$ ?

Second question:
To what extent are these following (increasingly general) statements true?

> Let $R$ be a DVR. Let $f\in R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be such that $(f)$ is prime, then $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$ is regular if and only if $f\notin\mathfrak{m}^2$ for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ containing $f$.
>
> Let $S$ be an integral domain of dimension $d$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal such that $S/\mathfrak{p}$ has dimension $d-k$, then $S/\mathfrak{p}$ is regular if and only if for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $S$ containing $\mathfrak{p}$, the image of $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ generates a sub-(vector)-space of dimension $k$.

Thorough proofs or references to thorough proofs would be appreciated.

thanks,

- will

Comment: For the second question you don't need $(f)$ to be prime. In my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236545/local-ring-at-a-non-singular-point-of-a-plane-algebraic-curve/236665#comment524099_236665) I gave a proof for the local case that extends easily to the global case.

Comment: As far as I can see you have also a third question. This seems to be false for $\mathfrak p=0$.

Answer (score 2):

(1) the cotangent space is $(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{p})/(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{p})^2 = \mathfrak{m}/(\mathfrak{m}^2 + \mathfrak{p})$.